# How to estimate the nested conditional expectation?

Tags: estimation, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Given the continuous random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$, I want to estimate $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x, Z\right]$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x, Z\right]\mid Z\right]$. Are there any ways to estimate the two quantities? In general, we do not have enough points of $(Y,Z)$ when $X=x$ in estimating $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x, Z\right]$, but I guess I can estimate $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x, Z\right]$ by estimating $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X, Z\right]$ (after estimating the quantity, we substitute $X=x$ to obtain the estimated relation of $\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x, Z\right]$). How about the quantity $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid X=x, Z\right]\mid Z\right]$?